# RT-PCR v PCR Test for entry into Belarus

Tags: air-travel, europe, covid-19, belarus

I need to travel to Belarus from Berlin in the next two weeks and according to the government's website, foreigners need to present a valid PCR test that is not older than 72 hours. When I visit the website coronatest.de, it offers a RT-PCR test. From a quick google search, it is my understanding that they are the same "level" of tests except the RT-PCR test is in real-time.

My question is then as the following: Will the RT-PCR test be valid for entry into Belarus?

Comment: RT in RT-PCR does not mean real-time. It means reverse transcription. As far as I know, the only PCR test in use is actually an RT-PCR test, "PCR" is just a more general term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, they mean the same thing.**

RT doesn't mean real-time but reverse transcription. This refers to the process of converting the viral RNA into DNA that the PCR method can then amplify.

Because coronaviruses are RNA viruses, any PCR-based testing for them requires reverse transcription first. All "PCR" tests that anyone talks about now are thus correctly called [RT-PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_transcription_polymerase_chain_reaction).

Comment: Of course, there are also real-time RT-PCR which sometimes confuses people and many use the acronym incorrectly (instead of using rRT-PCR or qRT-PCR etc.). But in any case, there is not really a distinction useful for non-researchers. Most approved PCR tests are real-time and no country as far as I know currently distinguish the exact types of PCR test for travel purposes.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. I think I was looking at the wrong RT. Thank you for your helpful insight :)